# C++ Returning values from dynamic array (image class)

Tags: c++, arrays, image, pointers

I have a problem with the following code (compiler not complaining but I get an error message at runtime - R6010 abort). Basically I have created an Image class which reads data from an image and stores it in a dynamically allocated array. I then want to pass the image data into anther array in int main. For some reason this does not work.

```
class Image
{
private:
    char* charImage;
    int TotRows;
    int TotCol;
    int Size;
    int MaxVal;
    char Magic[2];

public:
    Image();
    Image (const Image& Orig);
    ~Image();
    void operator=(const Image&); //overloaded assignment operator
    void ReadImage();
    char ReturnImage(int i);
    int getSize();
};

Image::Image()//constructor
{
    Size = (3 * TotRows * TotCol);
    charImage = new char [Size];
}

Image::Image (const Image& Orig)//copy constructor
{
    TotRows = Orig.TotRows;
    TotCol = Orig.TotCol;
    Size = Orig.Size;
    charImage = new char [Size];
}

Image::~Image()//destructor
{

    delete []charImage;
}

void Image::operator=(const Image& Orig)
{
    TotRows = Orig.TotRows;
    TotCol = Orig.TotCol;
    Size = Orig.Size;
    charImage = new char [Size];

    for (int i = 0; i < Size; i++)
    {
        charImage[i]=Orig.charImage[i];
    }
}

void Image::ReadImage()
{
    //opening original image
    ifstream OldImage;
    OldImage.open ("image2.ppm", ios::in | ios::binary);

    if (!OldImage)
        cout << "\nError: Cannot open image file! " << endl;

    //reading the header of the original image file
    OldImage >> Magic [0] >> Magic [1];

    //if the image is not in the right format, do not proceed!
    if ((Magic [0] != 'P')||(Magic [1] != '6'))
        cout << "\nError: image is in the wrong format!" << endl;

    else
        OldImage >> TotRows >> TotCol >> MaxVal;

    //reading the image in binary format and storing it in the array of characters
    OldImage.read(charImage, Size);

}

char Image::ReturnImage(int i)
{
    return charImage[i];
}
int Image::getSize()
{
    return Size;
}

int main ()
{
    char* charImage;
    int Size;
    Image myImage;
    myImage.ReadImage();
    Size = myImage.getSize();

    charImage= new char [Size];

    for (int i=0; i<Size; i++)
    {
        charImage[i]=myImage.ReturnImage(i);
    }

    delete [] charImage;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

One obvious error is that you don't set the dimensions of the image int he default constructor:

```
Image::Image()//constructor
{
    Size = (3 * TotRows * TotCol);
    charImage = new char [Size];
}
```

Here, `TotRows` and `TotCol` are uninitialized, and could have any value.

Then, in the assignment operator, you do not deallocate the array pointed at by `charImage` before making it point to a new array, so you are leaking resources.

Comment: THanks! that's exactely what the problem was. thanks so much for helping me out

Answer (score 0):

When you create an instance of Image (myImage), the TotRows and TotCol members are uninitialized. Who knows what's the value of 'Size' in the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from others comment,

From my understanding, you do not want to proceed if the image is not in the right 
format, but still you do reading the image.

```
  //if the image is not in the right format, do not proceed!
    if ((Magic [0] != 'P')||(Magic [1] != '6'))
        cout << "\nError: image is in the wrong format!" << endl;

    else
        OldImage >> TotRows >> TotCol >> MaxVal;
```

You read the image irrespective of the image format.

```
    //reading the image in binary format and storing it in the array of characters
    OldImage.read(charImage, Size);
```

Hope it helps to some extend.